# html table add three column in one column as title

Tags: html, css

How can I put the 3 column inside the one column like this as a title.

###### desired implementation

[image: main image]

###### my implementation

[image: my image]

###### markup

```html
<th colspan="3">Caution definitive</th>
<th colspan="3">Retenu de Garantie</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `colspan` in your markup to spread cells over multiple colums twice, but for your desired implementation you'd need it only once and instead the first (visible) cell should reach over two rows. This is done with `rowspan`.

Put aside the difference between posted markup and implementation, this will produce the desired output:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Date de Reception Definitive</th>
        <th colspan="3">Caution Definitive</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Montant</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've added borders for clarity.